# Search for keyword and then conditional on finding it search for another keyword from a list of words using Perl

Tags: perl, search

My question concerning Perl is very similar to the one involving Python answered here:
[How can I search within a document for a keyword and then subsequent key words within a set number of lines of the original keyword in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825055/how-can-i-search-within-a-document-for-a-keyword-and-then-subsequent-key-words-w)

This involves searching for one keyword and then for another from a list of keywords (say you have a list of 4 words) in the vicinity of the original keyword (say plus minus 5 lines) and then when matched printing out a range of lines (say plus minus 20 lines from the original keyword)

Two extensions if possible:

Ext 1: in the printout highlight key words

Ext 2: search all files from a directory and add the filename to the printout (filename in one line, followed by the lines extracted from the file)

I would appreciate even if directed to similar examples...

Answer (score 1):

1. Read in  the File as a nice array:

   ```
   my @line = <FILE>;
   ```
2. Search for the 1st word:

   ```
   my $i;
   foreach $i (0 .. $#line) {
     last if $line[$i] =~ /$firstWord/i;
   }
   ```
3. Get the surrounding using an array slice:

   ```
   my @surrounding = @line[$i-5 .. $i+5];
   ```

   One should however use some index checking like

   ```
   [0<=$i-5 ? 0 : $i-5 .. $i+5<@line ? $i+5 : $#line]
   ```
4. repeat
5. Profit

The rest is left as an exercise to the reader.

For highlighting write

```
    $line[$i] =~ s{($firstWord)}{<strong>$1</strong>};
```

or similar, depending on your output medium. `map` is your friend for this.